# International SEO with different TLD's, and some same language - HREFLANG question

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing, duplicate-content, hreflang

My business is located in Asia although 50% of my clients are from the UK, 27% from Australia and the remaining in the country i am located.

After doing research i have concluded that i would like to use my .com for international and my home country, .co.uk for the UK and .com.au for Australia.

I believe using the below hreflang would work and stop me from receiving any duplicate content issues? Can anyone advise?

Im curious because Australian English and the UK English are basically the same.

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://example.com/" 
  hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://example.co.uk/" 
  hreflang="en-gb" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://example.com.au" 
  hreflang="en-au" />
```

Comment: Can anyone help? :)